# Runtime Error: R6025 -- Unable to see location of program causing the error

Tags: windows-7, windows, runtime-error

[image: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library, Runtime Error!, Program: C:..., R6025, - pure virtual function call]

I've been receiving this error every few days but have no idea what program is causing it.  The error window isn't resizable, so I'm not able to see the program's location.  Is there some other way I can find out what program is causing this? (*Finding the program location is my main objective, see below for the reasoning,)

It doesn't occur when I've just opened/closed a program (Googling, I noticed other people were getting runtime errors when they would open a program, that's not the case for me), it randomly appears while I'm in the middle of doing something (e.g. browsing on Chrome, editing a video, etc. or even with nothing actively open and just looking at a blank Desktop).  Nothing crashes when the error comes up either, all active windows and programs in the system tray stay active.

*:Given how unoften it happens it would be pretty difficult to take suggestions on how to fix the error itself (because I wouldn't be able to simply answer "did it work?" for maybe a week at a time).  For now I think I'll just focus on suggestions for finding the specific program that's causing the error, from there I should be able to search and find the solution myself.

Text version of error:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Runtime Error! 
Program: C:... 
R6025 
- pure virtual function call
```

Comment: Did you checked event viewer for the error logs?

Comment: Please review this [article][1] and reply back with details on whether any of the solutions resolved your issue. 

  [1]: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/runtime-error-p6025-pure-virtual-function-call-on/89e10d2f-b949-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find source process of unknown popup in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/881604/how-to-find-source-process-of-unknown-popup-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the crosshair from toolbar

[image: Process Explorer CrossHair]

and move it to the Error message. This will highlight the program which causes the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is often the case when runtime components of Visual C++ libraries are missing.

Quoting from [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/runtime-error-p6025-pure-virtual-function-call-on/89e10d2f-b949-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5):

Follow the methods listed below:

Method 1:

This error may occur when the Microsoft .NET Framework installation on the computer is damaged or is missing.

Try the below step to reinstall and repair the Microsoft .NET Framework installation on the computer and later check if you can install the software.

a) Click the Start button, click  Control Panel, click Programs, and then click "Turn Windows features on or off." If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

b) Locate Microsoft .NET framework 3.5.1, uncheck the box, click OK and restart the computer.

c) After the restart again open "Turn Windows features on or off" and place  a check mark next to Microsoft .NET framework 3.5.1 and restart the computer.

Step 2

If the issue is caused due to missing Visual C++ libraries, you may download and install the Runtime components of Visual C++ libraries from the link below:

[Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package for (X86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=32BC1BEE-A3F9-4C13-9C99-220B62A191EE&displaylang=en)
[Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Packager for (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb4ebe2d-33c0-4a47-9dd4-b9a6d7bd44da&displaylang=en)
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en)
[Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package for (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=BA9257CA-337F-4B40-8C14-157CFDFFEE4E&displaylang=en)
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)

If you don't know which program is causing the error it's hard to guess what version you need - I'd try the latest one first.