# How to find source process of unknown popup in Windows 7

Tags: windows, security, process, window

A random popup appears in Windows 7 titled as `Information` with a progress bar and a clock. The window sometimes says `Please wait a moment...`, and the progress bar moves very slowly and disappears.

[image]

I don't know the source of this popup. I tried to search regarding this popup on the Internet, and some people had this problem. It also has a question on Yahoo! Answers, but everyone told to scan for malware and viruses.

**Is there any way to know the source process for this window/popup?**

- The task manager shows nothing about this window
- The only tasks that are running are Google Chrome, etc.
- Right-click and left-click does not work on this window or its title bar.

Comment: Since you accepted an answer, can you tell what process it was and if it was malicious ? Thanks.

Comment: This quickly resembles the window that showed when you were mounting a drive using Daemon tools.

Comment: It was not any malicious software but Zemana Antilogger Free. Reinstalling the software solved the issue(For now atleast).

Comment: That looks like it was made with Delphi, using this tool for their exceptions: http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm.. This is the same tool we use for our exception handling where I work. if it was popping up randomly it means the program was getting bugs

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can identify the application by getting [**Process Explorer** tool from Microsoft SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

At the toolbar, locate and use the following tool:

[image]

If you drag & drop it over unknown window, its process will become highlighted in the list.

What you can do then is to right-click that process and select **Check VirusTotal** to see whether the image is valid and well-known.

You can also double-click the process to learn about its EXE path, parent process or company who created it.

Comment: Works usually. I managed to get one to say csrss.exe this way.

Comment: @Joshua That is the process that started the command. Sometimes you find things like `dllhost.exe /start c:/evil/file/here.exe` or similar. The example given is just an example, but it happens a lot. The `/start` part is mockup. When you see it in the task manager, it is simply a `dllhost.exe` process running. You need to see the full command.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the arguments to the session of csrss.exe that is running the currently logged in session aren't of much use.

Comment: [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) can do this too, and is much more actively maintained. It has every feature of Process Explorer that I know of and then some (speaking as a long term Process Explorer user frustrated with lack of progress).