# What are these shortcut hints, and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

Periodically, I will see this:

[image]

What causes them, and how do I get rid of them without rebooting? I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: Weird, looks like a video artifact problem, left over (or misprinted) by some application you were/are using. Try tapping "Alt" once to see if that hides them.  Have you tried upgrading your video driver to the latest version offered by the manufacturer?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this coming from few different applications already. Yours are mini tooltips showing keyboard shortcuts to commands in ribbon menu. They are **windows** on their own, not only some graphic leftovers painted on desktop. They most likely belong to some application which uses [ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)) interface.

1. [Find the owner of these windows](https://superuser.com/a/881610/287473).
2. Exit that application (or kill it if exiting is not possible) and they are gone.

Comment: @James – please let me know how it worked for you. If you found out something else, feel free to post your own answer and accept it.