# What is this floating number "5" icon that Visual Studio is generating?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Windows 10, and I will frequently see a grey number on my screen. It looks like this [image]

It's not always on the taskbar. I've seen it other places on my screen. I'm pretty sure it's always the number 5, although I'm not entirely sure about that. I can't seem to interact with it at all.

Using Process Explorer, I've identified the program generating the icon as Visual Studio 2015. Closing Visual Studio makes the icon go away, although opening it back up doesn't immediately bring it back.

Does anyone know what this is, or what part of Visual Studio is generating it?

Comment: Does this approach work? http://superuser.com/a/881610/33047

Comment: @MartinSmith Hmm. It says it's Visual Studio. And indeed, closing Visual Studio makes it go away. But I still don't know what it actually is.

Comment: Maybe tag this with visual studio then and see if someone recognizes it.

Comment: If you move your taskbar back to the bottom of the screen, does the number stay at the top or does it move with the taskbar?

Comment: It stays at the top. Sometimes it goes behind the taskbar, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it could be the VS-icon shows the # of notification messages as a number overlay on the icon when the application is minimized.
When you have Visual Studio opened does it show any notifications (with the flag symbol) in the top-right of the VS window ?